# When is the best time to install solar tubes in relation to a new roof?

Tags: roofing, solar-tubes

My roof will need to be replaced next year, perhaps a complete tear-off. I'm also considering installing one or more solar tubes. I'm thinking it would be wise to wait for a new roof before installing the tubes, but the winters in upstate NY get very dreary and we could really use the extra light soon. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you did the solar tubes before the new roof (or together with the new roof), then the roofers would be the ones flashing in the solar tubes--I'd trust roofers to do a proper flashing job more than I'd trust whoever is installing the solar tubes.

Answer (score 1):

If your doing the work yourself its only your time you wasting but if your paying someone then its your money.  Flashing for solar tubes is not that bad just an oversized plumbing vent.  If your roof is in bad condition it could be a project because the shingles will break apart if they are too old a brittle. You May need to buy a bundle of shingles to replace the shingles you break.

Comment: The roof is old and I didn't think of old brittle shingles giving me problems. I plan to do the tubes myself, but not the major roofing job. This has been a very helpful answer. Thanks.